# Find nature of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{\ln(n+1)}}{n^{\ln(an+1)}},$$ and problem asks for nature of that series, discussed after values of parameter $a$.
I tried with D'Alembert method but seems to become so complicated and get no result.

Comment: @coreyman317  Typo:  $\ln (an)=\ln(a)+ \ln(n)\neq \ln(a)\times \ln(n)$.

Comment: I would also note that the summand can be written as $\frac{1}{n^{\ln \frac{an +1}{n+1}}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\log(n+1)-\log(an+1)=\log\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)-\log\left(1+\dfrac1{an}\right)-\log a
\\=\left(1-\frac1a\right)\frac1n+o\left(\dfrac1n\right)-\log a.$$

Then the general term is asymptotic to $n^{-\log a}$ (because $\sqrt[n]n$ tends to $1$), for which the convergence condition is known.